# \n not working in textview android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, jsoup, format-specifiers

I am working on an application in which i parse an XML file using jsoup from site and show it on textview. The problem i am getting is that format specifier \n which is included in RSS is not wprking. Instead of going into the new line it just showing \n as it is. here is my code

```
    hello = sb.toString();
        String title, description = null;
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(hello);
        Elements a = document.getElementsByTag("item");
        for (Element element : a) {
            title = element.child(0).text();
            description = element.getElementsByTag("description").get(0).text();
            String src = Jsoup.parse(description).select("img").first().attr("src");
            String id = Jsoup.parse(description).select("id").text();
              description = Jsoup.parse(description).text();

               description = description.replace(id, "");
              description =  description.replace("/", "\\");

            list.add(new News(title,  id, src, description ));
```

the description contains \n tags but on text view its not working as shown in figure. as you can see in the first line instead of going into the new line \n showing as it is.
[image]

Comment: @TechnoCracker i am newbie in android.. could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Where you store your description?

Comment: nowhere. i just parse and show it on screen.

Comment: I gave you one example...  tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("Name" + "<br/>" + "<b>Chirag Savsani</b>"));

Comment: <br> break line n following output display in new line...

Comment: it means i need <br> instead of \n ? let me try.

Comment: Ya but it work only in Html.fromHtml().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try it with this:

```
 description= description.replaceAll("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

because a slash \ has to be a kind of "castet", this You can do with one slash \.

Comment: why are you replacing \\\n instead of \n?

Comment: you have to cast  a slash with two slashes \\, i think, don´t sure about but if it does not work, delete one slash and tell it to me, to correct the answer

Comment: i have just added your code but its not working.. do i need to do some thing else before adding your code? actually i have \n instead of \\n.

Comment: can You give me an example how the original string of description is? I mean without any replacement..

Comment: its same as its shown in my figure added in question.

Comment: use `replace("\\n", "\n");` instead of `replaceAll("\\n", "\n");`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps add another replace call to replace instances of `"\\n"` with `"\n"`

Comment: Maybe one could even create an infinite loop of replacement ? If it doesn't work the first time, why would it work the second time around ?

Comment: I typed 2 backslashes but the answer only rendered one for some reason

Comment: use `replace("\\n", "\n");`